# If $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$, as $x \to x_0$, can we always say $f(x) \to f(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Assuming $$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$

As $x$ approaches $x_0\ $i.e. $(x\to x_0)$, can we always say $f(x)$ approaches $f(x_0)\ $ i.e. $(f(x)\to f(x_0))$? From what I understand, this is the motivation for the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit.

The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition states that- $\forall \epsilon$, $\exists \delta$, such that:

$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. For any value of $\epsilon$ if I can provide a $\delta$, then $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ at $x_0$.

Approach is apparently an informal idea, and not what the limit defines. So the idea of $f(x)$ getting closer to $f(x_0)$, as $x$ gets closer to $x_0$ is inaccurate and not always true.

**Update:** The statement apparently is true, when $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. Though I have been unable to find a general proof for it yet.

Comment: Why this wouldn't be true for constant functions?

Comment: @CélioAugusto, this is just my understanding but, if $f(x)=a$, then for any value of $x$, $f(x)$ is always constant. If I'm trying to find its limit at a point $x_0$, as $x$ approaches $x_0$, I cannot say $f(x)$ approaches $a$.

Comment: sure you can. $\epsilon - \delta$ definition doesn't fail in your example. The word approach may imply some kind of motion in some sense, but if you think about it there isn't any better approach of $a$ than itself.

Comment: @alphaomega, if I don't think of approach as some kind of change occurring, I can probably say that. Thanks.

Comment: Also as long as $\epsilon-\delta$ is satisfied, can we say for any function there is an approach?

Comment: You could, but remember that "approach" is just an intuitive concept, not a formal one.

Comment: Yes, but I've thought about limits in terms of approach until now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h)=L$ then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|h|<\delta$ then $|f(x_0+h)-L|<\varepsilon$.

This means, for the same value of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then, setting $h=x-x_0$ we have $|f(x)-L|=|f(x_0+h)-L|<\varepsilon$, so the definition of $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to x_0$ is satisfied.

Note that this is actually slightly stronger than saying $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to x_0$, as $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h)=L$ also implies that $f(x_0)=L$, whereas in the definition of "$f(x)\to L$ as $x\to x_0$" it doesn't matter whether $f(x_0)$ even exists (or, if it does, what value it takes).

Comment: How does $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h)=L$, mean $L=f(x_0)$? $f(x_0)$ could be undefined. Also does $x \to x_0$ always imply $f(x) \to L$? You have me confused.

Comment: @KraZZ the point is that in the definition of $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to x_0$ we generally take the extra condition that $x$ is not allowed to actually equal $x_0$ (as in the definition you give above).